# Looking for a function with specific properties

Tags: calculus, integration, limits, improper-integrals

I am looking for a differentiable function $f$ that satisfies all of the following:

$$(\text{I}) \lim_{x\rightarrow 0^{+}}f(x) \rightarrow \infty$$

$$(\text{II}) \lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}f(x) \rightarrow 0$$

$$(\text{III}) f(x)>0 \space \forall \space x>0$$

$$(\text{IV}) \int_{0}^{\infty}f(x)dx \space \text{is finite and can be computed using elementary functions}$$

---

I failed to find such function.

---

Your help would be appreciated. THANKS!

Comment: Is that integrable?

Comment: @insipidintegrator asking me or asking Flat Pencil?

Comment: I am asking @FlatPencil but I just want to know so if you know it definitively them please tell me

Comment: @insipidintegrator I know that is a wrong answer

Comment: Your function can't be differentiable at $0$. Try e.g. $\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x}}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for a function defined on $(0, \infty)$ which is differentiable also on $(0, \infty)$, then the following example should work (if you consider exponential function as an elementary).

Consider a function

$$
f(x)=
\begin{cases}
x^{-1/2}, 0 < x < 1;\\
e^{1/2-1/2x}, x \geq 1.
\end{cases}
$$

Clearly $f(x)$ satisfies (I) and (II). Considering (III), $f(x)$ is obviously differentiable on $(0, 1)$ and on $(1, \infty)$. But $(x^{-1/2})' = -\frac{1}{2}x^{-3/2}$, so the left derivative at 1 is 1. On the other hand, $(e^{1/2-1/2x})' = -\frac{1}{2}e^{1/2-1/2x}$, so the right derivative at 1 is also 1, which means that $f(x)$ is differentiable on the whole $(0, \infty)$.

Finally, the integral of $f(x)$ can be computed as
$$
\int_0^\infty f(x)dx = \int_0^1 x^{-1/2}dx + \int_1^\infty e^{1/2-1/2x}dx = 2x^{1/2} \rvert_0^1 -2 e^{1/2-1/2x} \rvert_1^\infty = 2 - 0 - 0 + 2 = 4.
$$

Comment: Thanks. I found also $f(x)=\frac{1}{x^2+\sqrt{x}}$.

Comment: Oh, yes, good one. Though you have to use arctan to calculate it, right?

Comment: Right, arctan is used. (✓ for your answer).